# How to map id with an array of objects to display name property in view- Angular

Tags: arrays, angular

How can I map institution_id, field_id from api by their name in the arrays from local data service to display names in angular?
I am displaying a list of educations, which i get as a response from server.
In HTML file:

```
     <div *ngFor="let education of educations">
      <div class="col-2">
       <p>{{education.institution_id}}</p>
       <p>{{education.field_id}}</p>
      </div>
     </div>
```

From the api I am getting an array of objects named educations.
in TS file:

```
    educations = [{institution_id:'1',field_id:'1'}, 
                 {institution_id:'2',field_id:'2'}}];
```

I have a data service locally in which I have these two arrays.

```
     Institutions = [{id:1,name:"University A"},{id:2,name:"University B"}];
     Fields = [{id:1, name:"Field A"},{id:2, name:"Field B"}];
```

My question is about to map two arrays to display institution_name,field_name in html file.

Answer (score 1):

just map it in your code into a useful data structure...

```
this.mappedEducations = this.educations.map(e => {
  return {
    institution: Institutions.find(i => i.id === e.institution_id)?.name,
    field: Fields.find(f => f.id === e.field_id)?.name,
  }
})
```

then just use it in html...

```
 <div *ngFor="let education of mappedEducations">
  <div class="col-2">
   <p>{{education.institution}}</p>
   <p>{{education.field}}</p>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thnx. it worked.
I just changed a little bit-
field: Fields.find(f => f.id == +e.field)